# Splash Screen não aparece no app flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, estou tendo problemas em mostrar o Splash Screen no meu aplicativo flutter e gostaria de ajuda. Ao abrir o aplicativo ele aparece, mas só fica visível por 1 segundo, mesmo eu colocando um timer de 3 segundos. Isso ocorreu aparentemente depois de ter adicionado o SharedPreferences.

Segue o código:
main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserModel>(
      create: (context) => UserModel(),
      child: Consumer<UserModel>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Onde Está?',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
           
            home: SplashPage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

splash_page.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onde_esta/app/share/constant.dart';
import 'package:onde_esta/app/views/list_object.dart';
import 'package:onde_esta/app/widgets/home_page.dart';

String finalEmail;

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SplashPageState createState() => SplashPageState();
}

class SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  Future getValidationDate() async {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var obtainedEmail = sharedPreferences.getString('email');
    setState(() {
      finalEmail = obtainedEmail;
    });
    print('$finalEmail');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getValidationDate().whenComplete(() async {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return finalEmail == null ? HomePage() : ObjectListScreen();
      }));
    });
    super.initState();
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
      () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build...
```

Erro no console:

```
E/flutter (11382): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (11382): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
E/flutter (11382): #0      State.context.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1088
E/flutter (11382): #1      State.context 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1094
E/flutter (11382): #2      SplashPageState.initState.<anonymous closure> 
package:onde_esta/…/widgets/splash_page.dart:37
E/flutter (11382): #3      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
E/flutter (11382): #4      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (11382): #5      _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter (11382): #6      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter (11382): #7      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter (11382): #8      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (11382): #9      _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:1186:23)
E/flutter (11382): #10     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (11382): #11     _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
E/flutter (11382): #12     _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
E/flutter (11382): #13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo porque o método `getValidationDate()` está sendo executado antes da tela ser construída e por isso não tem como atualizar a tela com o `setState` antes da tela ser construída.

Em vez de usar o `Timer`, utilize o `Future.delayed`.

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou para mim!